# list index out of range error with python - linear search code

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to code a linear search algorithm where the user must input and search for specific items. In my example, if they type the correct word, the code successfully displays the message found message. However, if I type a word that is not in the list, it gives me an error.

```
wordlist = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'omg', 'test']

found = False 
index = 0 
search_item = input("Please type in the word that you would like to search")
while found == False: 
    if search_item == wordlist[index]: 
        print("Word found at index ", index)
        found = True 
    else: 
        index = index + 1 

if found == False:
    print("Item not in list")
```

---

When I run the code and type in a word that is not in the list, I get this error

```
if search_item == wordlist[index]: #check if the word the user typed matches the current item in the list
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you have no condition to break your loop, if `found` remains `False`, which it will if you enter an item not in your list, because your `index` param has no idea about the length of the list you'll need to add some logic about that

Comment: Add a second condition to the `while` statement - comparing `i` to the length of the search space.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to break out of the while loop -> checking that the current index is less than the size of the list `index<len(wordlist)`.

Try this:

```py
while found == False and index<len(wordlist): 
    if search_item == wordlist[index]: 
        print("Word found at index ", index)
        found = True 
    else: 
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer does work, there are changes which should be made to the program as a whole.

Some general notes:

- Unless there is a specific reason not to, `wordlist` should be renamed `word_list`.
- There is no need to compare boolean values using `==`. You can simply write `while bool:`,  `if not bool:`, etc.
- When iterating over some some structure `for` loops are generally superior to `while` loops. If we did want to iterate over the indices we could write `for index in range(len(word_list)):`.

---

First, here is a method which doesn't generalize as well as it could, but is just fine for your situation.

```py
for idx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if word == search_item:
        print(f'Word found at index {idx}')
        break
else:
    print('Item not in list')
```

`enumerate()` is a wonderful function which creates pairs of `(counter, element)` for each `element` of an object which can be iterated over. You can read more about it in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). In this case, `enumerate()` uses the default starting value of 0 for the counter, which means it corresponds to each element's index/position in the list.

The other noteworthy aspect of this program is the `else`. Straight from the [relevant part](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) of the python tutorial:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Since we only `break` out of the loop if we found the item, we know that the code in the `else` statement is only executed when the item wasn't found.

---

This next method looks rather silly here but makes a lot of sense when the search conditions, or the operations you want to perform on the result, are more complex.

For the sake of variety and clarity, `found_item` is no longer a boolean but a string.

```py
found_item = "nah"
found_idx = None

for idx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if word == search_item:
        found_item = "yay"
        found_idx = idx
        break

if found_item == "yay":
    print(f'Word found at index {found_idx}')
elif found_item == "nah":
    print('Item not in list')
```

---

Finally, lists (amongst others) have a method named [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) which returns the (first) index of the given element if it is in the list, or throws an error if it isn't. Throwing an error is not ideal, but you can always create a simple wrapper function to take care of it.

```py
found_item = False
found_idx = None

try:
    found_idx = word_list.index(search_item)
    found_item = True
except ValueError:
    pass

if found_item:
    print(f'Word found at index {found_idx}')
else:
    print('Item not in list')
```

---

Let me know if anything isn't clear or you have any further questions :)